# Getting the inside of a specific html tag, multiple occurring

Tags: javascript, rss

I have a an XML which is an RSS feed containing 400 or so items. Inside it is a repeating line:

```
<span class="rtm_due_value">Tue 29 Jan 13</span>
```

This is where the date will change based on the post. What I want to do is to count how many times I get a date which is within the last 48 hours. Right now I've got a script which counts the number of entry elements which gives the total, though this is for the full list.

Thanks in advance,
Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var spans = document.querySelectorAll('.rtm_due_value'),
    _48h = new Date() - 172800000; // <= 48h in ms

spans = [].filter.call(spans, function(span) {
  return new Date(span.textContent) - _48h > 0;
});

var howMany = spans.length;
```

Comment: Thanks, while this cut the number down from 420 it's now at 36. Though, from my testing there should only be 7 results. I'll play around and see what can be done. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries, it seems the result is always 29 over the amount that it should be, so I can use that modifier to get the correct answer. Thank you!